# copy multiple files from directory tree to new different tree; bash script

Tags: linux, bash, cp

I want to write a script that do specific thing:

I have a txt file e.g.

```
from1/from2/from3/apple.file;/to1/to2/to3;some not important stuff
from1/from2/banana.file;/to1/to5;some not important stuff
from1/from10/plum.file;/to1//to5/to100;some not important stuff
```

Now i want to copy file from each line (e.g. apple.file), from original directory tree to new, non existing directories, after first semicolon (;).

I try few code examples from similar questions, but nothing works fine and I'm too weak in bash scripting, to find errors.
Please help :)

need to add some conditions:
file not only need to be copy, but also rename. Example line in file.txt:

```
from1/from2/from3/apple.file;to1/to2/to3/juice.file;some1
from1/from2/banana.file;to1/to5/fresh.file;something different from above
```

so apple.file need to be copy and rename to juice.file and put in to1/to2/to3/juice.file
I think thaht cp will also rename file but

```
mkdir -p "$to"
```

from answer below will create full folder path with juice.file as folder

In addidtion after second semicolon in each line will be something different, so how to cut it off?
Thanks for all help

EDIT: There will be no spaces in input txt file.

Comment: Could you post the _few code examples from similar questions_ that you tried?

Comment: I write something simple like:

while read line           
do           
    cp "$ line"           
done < file.txt  

then i want to find how to create dest folder if it doesn't exist:

test -d "$d" || mkdir -p "$d" && cp file "$d"

Answer (score 1):

Try this code..

```
cat file | while IFS=';' read from to some_not_important_stuff
  do
    to=${to:1}  # strip off leading space
    mkdir -p "$to"  # create parent for 'to' if not existing yet
    cp -i "$from" "$to"  # option -i to get a warning when it would overwrite something
  done
```

Comment: Generally I think it works, thanks, but I have cp error "no such file or directory". Script should also create new directories like in txt file after first semicolon.

Comment: I added a needed `mkdir` before the copy to achieve that additional requirement.

Comment: I guess `/to1/to2/to3` is the folder, so no need direname on it.

Comment: Yes, you are right, and I already took that one out again (8 minutes ago ;-)

Comment: It works! Perfect job guys, thank you:) Fast & clean:) I have one error though: mkdir: `': no such f or d and cp the same.

Comment: That probably is an empty line in your input file or one that misses the obligatory semicolon.

Comment: Feel free to add an `echo "$from -> $to"` before the `mkdir` to have some output while this is running so you can see which line of input generates the error.

Comment: Issues with this: 1) what if there is no space to strip, or more than one? 2) I think you really want `mkdir -p "$(dirname "${to}")"`, as it seems the OP intends `${to}` to be the new *file* name, not the directory, and then 3) the destination for `cp` should probably be something like `"$(dirname "${to}")/."`...

Comment: The way OP specified his file suggests there will always be a space.   I also first thougt that the dirname would be needed and later decided against when I found that the given target probably is the directory only.

Answer (score 1):

Using awk

(run the awk command first and confirm the output is fine, then add **`|sh`** to do the copy)

```
awk -F";" '{printf "cp %s %s\n",$1,$2}' file |sh
```

Using shell (get updated that need manually create folder, base on alfe's

```
while IFS=';' read from to X
do
    mkdir -p $to
    cp $from $to 
done < file
```

Comment: you forgot to strip that leading space.

Comment: yes, different.  Try just that one:  `cp -i "/tmp/passwd" " /etc/passwd"` and you will see.  And for the case that there are spaces in the `to` value itself, you should put it in double quotes.  Then the `mkdir` will have the same issue.

Comment: delimiter semicolon still allows spaces in the path values, but I admit that very likely there will be no such spaces, and then your code will work fine.

Comment: @Alfe @BMW I manage to improve my script by save new variable `bnTo=$(basename ${to})` and insert into cp commant `cp -i "$from" "$(dirname "${to}")/${bnTo}"`. I also send errors to file `1>> error.log 2>&1`. My problem is that word `some` need to be '802' and I have error `not a valid identifier`

Comment: Okay, but isn't `bnTo=$(basename "${to}")` and then computing `"$(dirname "${to}")/${bnTo}"` resulting in the same as `"${to}"` alone?  I mean you split it into dir name and base name only to concat the two again?

Comment: You are right :P It works fine. i only have one error in first line `cat file | while IFS=';' read from to 802` like 802 not a valid identifier.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and used `tar` to solve it! Posted [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/602793/426791):

```
tmpfile=/tmp/myfile.tar
files="/some/folder/file1.txt /some/other/folder/file2.txt"
targetfolder=/home/you/somefolder

tar --file="$tmpfile" "$files"​
tar --extract --file="$tmpfile" --directory="$targetfolder"
```

In this case, `tar` will automatically create all (sub)folders for you! Best,

Nabi